# Changing value of a hidden field on postback

Tags: jquery, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, submit, hidden

I have spent all day trying to debug this and I need help.  I am developing a JQuery Mobile application in ASP.Net MVC 4.  I have a form with a hidden field on it, with a value that is derived from a model property:

```
@<input type="hidden" id="hdnShowMsg" name="hdnShowMsg" value="@Model.ShowMsg" />
```

After form submission, Model.ShowMsg is modified by the controller and then the form is redisplayed.  The problem is that by the time the view gets to its javascript (DOM fully loaded), Model.ShowMsg does not show the modified value but still shows the initial value (before the post).

I found this as a possible solution, which describes my situation almost exactly, however clearing the ModelState in the controller does not solve the issue:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-s-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value.aspx

I understand how the modelstate retains the form field values so it can redisplay them in case of a validation error.  I also understand that the HTML helpers in the view will use the ModelState first before using the model.  Why do I still have the issue if I clear the modelstate?

I put a breakpoint in the controller and verified that the modelstate was cleared, however when the view is redisplayed after the postback, the following javascript code displays the old value:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert(document.getElementById("hdnShowMsg").value);
    });
</script>
```

How can this be?

Here is the html helper for the form:

```
@Using Html.BeginForm("Index", "NewDocument", Model, FormMethod.Post, New With {.id = "newdocument-form"})
```

Comment: Maybe the page itself is being cached? Is it an ajax post? Are you passing your modified model back into the page in your controller?

Comment: I am using JQuery Mobile, which I understand uses Ajax posting by default.  Yes, I am passing the modified model back into the page from the controller.  I am using IE10 and I explicitly have the browser configured not to cache, so if the page is being cached it is happening by some other mechanism.

Comment: did you put debug point in controller and checked that value is updated to new value?

Comment: If its ajax the page doesn't actually get rebuilt by the server so your model won't update.

Comment: Yes, I put a debug point in the controller and verified the value is getting updated to the new value.

Comment: Jack, can you explain in further detail what you mean?  How can I code this to get the results I want?  All I want to do is to perform validation on the submitted fields after the submit, set this field value inside the model, and the resubmit the model to the view and have it display the field value in a javascript alert.  How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Jack, if the page is not getting rebuilt by the server, then why is it stopping at a breakpoint inside of the server-side page code?   The model does not seem to be the issue here, since the hidden field value is being properly set. The issue appears to be the DOM not getting updated since the last time the page was viewed.